# PHP, заполнить html таблицу данными с массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
$array = [
[
    "photo" => "0.jpg",
    "id" => "http://vk.com/id0",
    "name" => "Жекі"
],
[
    "photo" => "1.jpg",
    "id" => "https://vk.com/id1",
    "name" => "Рижий Олександр"
]
```

];

И вот так я заполнила таблицу:

```
<tr>
    <th>
      <img src="<?=$array[0]["photo"]?>">
    </th>
    <td>
        <a href="<?=$array[0]["id"]?>"> <?=$array[0]["name"]?> </a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>
        <img src="<?=$array[1]["photo"]?>">
       </th>
    <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="<?=$array[1]["id"]?>"> <?=$array[1]["name"]?></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

НО мне сказали, что это можно и нужно сделать проще и удобнее, т.е если будет ещё 10 людей в массиве, то не удобно писать один и тот же код в HTML, но я не могу понять как это сделать.
Подскажите, пожалуйста. И без использования AJAX или тому подобного. Чистый PHP

Comment: вы может таки почитаете какие нибудь книги по программированию, разделы где переменные, типы данных, операторы, условия, циклы?

Comment: @teran, да я читаю на php.net/manual, и параллельно прошу друга-программиста давать мне задания по этим темам, потому что мне (как, наверное, и любому человеку), проще разобрать ту или иную тему на практике. Но иногда захожу в ступоры, вот и лезу сюда)

Comment: вы книгу лучше возьмите. мануалы легко читать человеку более подготовленному, кто уже в теме и разбирается какие технологии и для чего используются. начинающим же проще взять книгу, а потом уже углублять знания используя документацию, в особенности если нет профильного образования

Comment: @teran, но я не настолько новичок) полгода учила javascript/html/css - могу свободно ими пользоваться. Даже если откинуть верстку, - основный функции (те самые for, while, foreach)не очень отличаются в php и js. Только среда использования иная. Если я неправа - простите, буду рада, если вы меня исправите

Comment: тогда не понятно, почему в данной задаче вы сразу не применили цикл, вроде же очевидно.

Comment: @teran, вроде бы очевидно, да. Сперва я и подумала о цикле, а именно for-е, потому что использую его чаще всего, но, как сказала выше, зашла в ступор .о. Написала, как говорится, говно-код, и у завис ноут. Решила с этим не экспериментировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<? foreach ($array as $a) { ?>
<tr>
    <th>
      <img src="<?=$a[0]["photo"]?>">
    </th>
    <td>
        <a href="<?=$a[0]["id"]?>"> <?=$a[0]["name"]?> </a>
    </td>
</tr> <? } ?>
```

Подробнее http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: и Вам спасибо :з

Answer (score 1):

Пример с [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
<?php foreach($array as $arr){ ?>
<tr>
    <th>
        <img src="<?=$arr[0]["photo"]?>">
    </th>
    <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="<?=$arr[0]["id"]?>"><?=$arr[0]["name"]?></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Пример с [for](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php):

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<=count($array); ){
    echo $array[$i]["id"];
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Пример с [while](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.while.php):

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($i <= count($array)){
    echo $array[$i]["id"];
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: спасибо, помогли :з foreach кажется намного удобнее)